# Pointer Math with Complex Array

Tags: c, arrays, fftw

I have this snippet of code with some pointer math that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int N, N2;
    fftwf_complex *box;
    fftwf_plan plan;
    float *smoothed_box;

    // Allocate memory for arrays (Ns are set elsewhere and properly,
    // I've just left it out for clarity)
    box = (fftwf_complex *)fftwf_malloc(N * sizeof(fftwf_complex));
    smoothed_box = (float *)malloc(N2 * sizeof(float));

    // Create complex data and fill box with it. Do FFT. Box has the
    // Hermitian symmetry that complex data has when doing FFTs with 
    // real data
    plan = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_3d(N,N,N,box,(float *)box,
         FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    ...

    // end fft

    // Now do the loop I don't understand
    for(i = 0; i < N2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N2; j++)
        {
            for(k = 0; k < N2; k++)
            {
                smoothed_box[R_INDEX(i,j,k)] = *((float *)box + 
                    R_FFT_INDEX(i*f + 0.5, j*f + 0.5, k*f +0.5))/V;
            }
        }
    }

    // Do other stuff
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Where f and V are just some numbers that are set elsewhere in the code and don't matter for this particular question. Additionally, the functions R_FFT_INDEX and R_INDEX don't really matter, either. What's important is that, for the first loop iteration ,when i=j=k=0, R_INDEX = 0 and R_FFT_INDEX=45. smoothed_box has 8 elements and box has 320.

So, in gdb, when I print smoothed_box[0] after the loop, I get smoothed_box[0] = some number. Now, I understand that, for an array of normal types, say floats, array + integer will give array[integer], assuming that integer is within the bounds of the array.

However, fftwf_complex is defined as typedef float fftw_complex[2], as you need to hold both the real and imaginary parts of the complex number. It's also being casted to a float * from a fftwf_complex *, and I'm unsure what this does, given the typedef.

All I know is that when I print box[45] in gdb, I get box[45] = some complex number that is not smoothed_box[0] * V. Even when I print *((float *)box + 45)/V, I get a different number than smoothed_box[0].

So, I was just wondering if anyone could explain to me the pointer math that is being done in the above loop? Thank you, and I appreciate your time!

Comment: Cast has higher precedence than +, so the addition will be multiplied by sizeof float.

Comment: If `R_FFT_INDEX` index is supposed to be an index of an `fftwf_complex` element relative to the pointer `box`, then dereference that element by index first, and extract the component you want from the resulting `fftwf_complex` object.  This is the simplest approach that is actually correct.

Comment: R_FFT_INDEX is a pointer relative to box, I think, but it's built in such a way so as to access the real data that's stored in box after the transform. I'm still confused as to how that works. @stark I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the addition will be multiplied by sizeof(float)? Does this mean it's actually element 4 * 45 (assuming a float is 4 bytes)?

Comment: When you add 45 to a pointer to a float, you add 45 * sizeof(float) to the number in the pointer.  Pointer arithmetic is always based on the type of object pointed to, which is why ++ works for pointers stepping through an array.

Comment: @stark I see. So, since fftwf_complex is defined as typedef float fftwf_complex[2], where [0] is the real part and [1] is the imaginary part, when it gets cast to a float *, *(float *)box + 45 would really be 45 * 4 bytes away from the first address? Is there a way to tell what element of box that corresponds to, or does that question not even make sense to ask in this case?

Comment: I would try to figure out how to eliminate the cast.  It is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box` is allocated as an array of `N` `fftwf_complex`. Then a backward 3D c2r fftw transform using `N,N,N` is performed on `box`, requiring `N*N*(N/2+1)` `fftwf_complex`. See  http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format Therefore, this code might trigger undefined behavior, such as segmentation fault, before reaching the pointer arithmetics...

It is practical to cast back `box` to an array of float because the DFT is performed in place. Indeed, `box` is used twice as the fftwf_plan is created. `box` is both the input array of complex and the output array of real:

```
plan = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_3d(N,N,N,box,(float *)box,
     FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

Once `fftwf_execute(plan);` is called, `box` is better seen as an array of real. Nevertheless, this array is of size `N*N*2*(N/2+1)`, where the items located at positions i,j,k where k>N-1 are meaningless. See [FFTW's Real-data DFT Array Format](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format.html#Real_002ddata-DFT-Array-Format):

> For an in-place transform, some complications arise since the complex data is slightly larger than the real data. In this case, the final dimension of the real data must be padded with extra values to accommodate the size of the complex data—two extra if the last dimension is even and one if it is odd. That is, the last dimension of the real data must physically contain 2 * (nd-1/2+1) double values (exactly enough to hold the complex data). This physical array size does not, however, change the logical array size—only nd-1 values are actually stored in the last dimension, and nd-1 is the last dimension passed to the planner.

This is the reason why the real array `smoothed_box` is introduced, though an `N*N*N` array would be expected. If `smoothed_box` were an array of size `N*N*N`, then the following conversion could have been performed:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
  for(j=0;j<N;j++){
    for(k=0;k<N;k++){
     smoothed_box[(i*N+j)*N+k]=((float *)box)[(i*N+j)*(2*(N/2+1))+k]
    }
  }
}
```